# NetworkManager does not support non-default routing tables

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

I configure the netplan of Ubuntu as below, with different routing tables.
However, I cannot apply the netplan, and the error information is:
"NetworkManager does not support non-default routing tables"

I cannot find any feasible method to solve this issue from google. I need your help.
Thank you very much.

[NetworkManager does not support non-default routing tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbnKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you go back and look at the example netplan configs you found online with:

```
routing-policy:
...
table: 192
```

You'll notice that they all have:

```
renderer: networkd
```

as opposed to your config which has:

```
renderer: NetworkManager
```

These are two different services for managing your network. NetworkManager gets installed when you install a desktop GUI for Ubuntu as opposed to the server version which uses systemd-network (called networkd in the netplan config file). The routing table feature is supported by systemd-network but not supported by NetworkManager.

I haven't tried changing the renderer in the netplan config from NetworkManager to networkd but I suspect that you'd have to disable NetworkManager for that to work (systemctl stop NetworkManager; systemctl disable NetworkManager). And unfortunately, disabling NetworkManager will disable the network GUI widget (shown up by the clock) in the desktop GUI so you'll lose the ability to configure the network with the graphical tool if you do disable NetworkManager.